# TSQL Geography STGeomFromText Displaying Wrong Result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geography

I'm trying to write a code which will tell me whether point is inside polygon or not

```
DECLARE @Latitude varchar(20) = '41.694110'
DECLARE @Longitude varchar(20) = '44.833680'
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @p geography;

DECLARE @PolygonString varchar(500) = 'POLYGON((41.711921 44.658505, 41.851703 44.773175, 41.763158 44.972302, 41.654421 44.843083, 41.711921 44.658505))'

SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@PolygonString, 4326);
SET @p = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)

SELECT @g.STIntersects(@p)
```

It always return 0. Here is visual representation of scenario.

http://sbtutor.com/

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any multipolygons in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in the geospatial types, but can give you some thoughts.
For the WKT string (the string you use to make the polygon), the pairs need to be long/lat rather than lat/long.

That said, I still could not get your polygon to be recognized as valid as a geography because I did not apply the counter-clockwise rule that Jaaz pointed out later. So I used the geometry type which is not as restrictive, and it worked correctly.

Using geometry for the polygon, the `POINT` has to be geometry as well. In which case, `geometry::POINT()` expects X,Y coordinates (lng/lat) instead of of the lat/lng pair used with the geography type.

So, this will yield true on the intersect:

```
DECLARE @Latitude float = 41.694110
DECLARE @Longitude float = 44.833680
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, 4326)
DECLARE @p geometry = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((44.658505 41.711921, 44.773175 41.851703, 44.972302 41.763158, 44.843083 41.654421, 44.658505 41.711921))', 4326);
SELECT @g.STIntersects(@p)
```

Comment: Jaaz corrected it keeping the geography type, so that is the correct answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I though Latitude was X and Longitude was Y, I finally find out that Longitude is X and Latitude is Y.
And I've changed my code from geography to geometry. Now everything makes sense. Thanks !!!

Comment: Just to be clear, the arguments for `geography::POINT()` are LAT,LONG,SRID. But the arguments for `geometry::POINT()` are X,Y,SRID. The x,y plane can be any cartesian plane, not just a map projection. But **if** you are using a map projection, then it corresponds to LONG,LAT (the opposite order when using geography).

Answer (score 3):

mdisbio's answer got me thinking about the ordering of arguments, so I had to reorder the points once I inverted the long/lat ordering per argument so as to adhere to the left hand rule, and it finally came out as intersecting.

```
DECLARE @Latitude varchar(20) = '41.694110'
DECLARE @Longitude varchar(20) = '44.833680'
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @p geography;

DECLARE @PolygonString varchar(500) = 'POLYGON((44.658505 41.711921, 44.843083 41.654421, 44.972302 41.763158, 44.773175 41.851703, 44.658505 41.711921))'

SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(@PolygonString, 4326);
SET @p = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)

SELECT @g.STIntersects(@p)
--1
```

So for [Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811(v=sql.105).aspx), the ordering is Lat/Long, but seemingly for polygons, the ordering is interpreted as Long/Lat. Keep that in mind, and this should be a breeze.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'left hand rule' so I understand this better? 'Counter-clockwise'? or something else? I know the points have to be in succession...

Comment: In succession and counter-clockwise is what I meant. In fact, geography objects (but not geometry objects) will fail to create if this rule's not applied.

Comment: I've tried exactly the same idea with little modification, What I did 
was 
SET @p = geography::Point(@Longitude, @Latitude, 4326)

But it doesn't make any sense. Well it worked but there was no logical explanation why it worked :D

Comment: If you have SSMS, you can issue `SELECT @g UNION ALL SELECT @p` and get a visual representation of your polygon and point and whether or not they intersect...